# Is there a way to manually create an ORM object in a persistent state?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, orm

I want to create an persistent ORM object from the some data i already have and deferred columns for everything else.

Simplified example - i have some code that loads data from several tables with multiple queries:

```py
def my_func(
    session: Session, country_code: str, user_email: str
) -> tuple[Country | None, User | None]:
    country = session.scalar(
        select(Country)
        .where(Country.code == country_code)
        .options(load_only(Country.id))
    )

    user = session.scalar(
        select(User)
        .where(User.email == user_email)
        .options(load_only(User.id, User.name))
    )

    return country, user
```

and i'd like to rewrite it with UNION ALL without changing interface:

```py
def my_func(
    session: Session, country_code: str, user_email: str
) -> tuple[Country | None, User | None]:
    country_query = (
        select(1, Country.id, None)
        .where(Country.code == country_code)
    )
    user_query = (
        select(2, User.id, User.name)
        .where(User.email == user_email)
    )
    result = session.scalars(union_all(country_query, user_query)).all()

    country_data = next((i[1] for i in result if i[0] == 1), None)
    user_data = next((i[1] for i in result if i[0] == 2), None)

    # somehow create ORM objects with received data and all other columns as deferred
    country = ... if country_data else None
    user = ... if user_data else None
    return country, user
```

The calling code relies on objects being there, and i'd like to avoid changing it.

Comment: Does the state have to be persistent? [Merging](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/session_state_management.html#merging) seems to do most of what you, but new instances won't be persistent unless you commit the session.

Comment: It seems to me that if you really want objects whose state is "persistent" then you'll need to hit the database twice, once for each object. Unless you want to try hacking the state of your new object to change it from "transient" to "persistent", which sounds like a really bad idea IMO.

Comment: @snakecharmerb i think so, otherwise object might be "persisted" again which sounds pretty bad. 

Merging - with load=True queries the db again, with load=False looked promising, but raised "sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: merge() with load=False option does not support objects transient (i.e. unpersisted) objects.".

Comment: @GordThompson
The example is simplified, actually i need to collect data from up to 7 different unrelated to each other tables. The whole point of this is to reduce number of roundtrips to the database, doing UNION and then N SELECTS defeats purpose, it would be better leave it as it is.

Yes, hacking is a bad idea, if i can't create persistent objects i'll just change calling code. 

There is something similar but for attributes: [set_committed_value](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.attributes.set_committed_value) ,so i thought there might be a way.

Comment: (cc: @snakecharmerb ) I came up with a roundabout solution [here](https://gist.github.com/gordthompson/14ae7aee3e83a1f0737cc2ab609394a6). It ain't pretty, but it does avoid the one-round-trip-per-object issue.

Comment: @GordThompson It seems too pricey. The bucket table must store the full cartesian product of all tables; assuming there are 5 tables with 100 rows in each, the bucket will contain 100^5 rows. Also, there is the bucket maintenance cost when data in the child tables changes.
But it's possible to achieve a similar result without physically storing data by doing left joins with a filtering join condition (i.e., t1.id = 1 instead of t1.id=t2.t1_id) - that's certanly one way to solve this, though I'm not sure how well DB would handle such query.

Comment: The row in the basket table is not committed; it only exists within the transaction so the select can do its job and then it is rolled back. So the basket table remains empty (in terms of permanently persisted rows) and there is no maintenance cost.

Comment: Oh, indeed, somehow missed that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @GordThompson's solution, I ended up doing something like this (in a more generic way though):

```
def my_func(
    session: Session, country_code: str, user_email: str
) -> tuple[Country | None, User | None]:
    col_ids = func.unnest(cast([0, 1], ARRAY(BigInteger))).alias()
    q = (
        select(
            col_ids.column,
        ).select_from(col_ids)
    )
    q = q.outerjoin(
        User,
        and_(col_ids.column == 0, User.email == user_email)
    ).add_columns(User)
    q = q.outerjoin(
        Country,
        and_(col_ids.column == 1, Country.code == country_code)
    ).add_columns(Country)
    
    result = {key: next(m for m in models if m) for key, *models in session.execute(q) if any(models)}
    return result.get(1), result.get(0)
```

The idea is to make a virtual root table with unnest() and then left join other tables to it.
With many joined tables, the result set will contain a lot of mostly empty columns, but for retrieving a small amount of rows it's fine, I think.
Postgresql seems to handle such query pretty well.